# Container.ItemIndex in Repeater - Rendering Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this line of code in a Repeater:-

```
<div class="paymentOptionsForm" onclick="$('.rbToken<%# Container.ItemIndex+1 %>>input').attr('checked', 'checked'); changeActiveType('token<%# Container.ItemIndex+1 %>', this);">
```

which renders fine in the HTML, as:-

```
<div class="paymentOptionsForm" onclick="$('.rbToken1>input').attr('checked', 'checked'); changeActiveType('token1', this);">
```

BUT (in the same repeater)

```
<div id="divTokenDropDown" class="tokenDecision<%# Container.ItemIndex+1 %>" runat="server">
```

is rendered as:-

```
<div id="ctl00_plcContentMain_CtlToken_rptcard_ctl00_divTokenDropDown" class="tokenDecision&lt;%# Container.ItemIndex+1 %>" style="display:block;">
```

I am not sure why this rendered in this way, other than it might be to do with the runat="server" but I need to leave this in here.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
<div id="divTokenDropDown" 
   class='<%# string.Format("tokenDecision{0}", Container.ItemIndex+1) %>' 
   runat="server">
```

There are a couple of other expressions that would work as well (like string.Concat).

I'm just speculating here, but I would guess that the `runat="server"` attribute meant that the parser treated the tag as a `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl`, which (I further guess) allows you to bind an attribute to an expression, but not mix a literal with an expression as an attribute value.  The first tag you used isn't a server control, and so the parser doesn't even interpret it as a tag, just as a place into which it needs to drop the value of an expression.

Comment: Thanks but that just shows class="&lt;%# string.Format(&quot;tokenDecision{0}&quot;, Container.ItemIndex+1) %>

Comment: Did you put the single quote on the outside of the expression and the double quote inside the expression? Look closely at which quote symbol I used where.

Comment: @superman1971  Please consider marking my answer as correct, if it helped you.